# C# y EF. No consigo insertar varios registros en un for, sólo inserta el último

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

Tengo un for que recorre una lista de checks y por cada uno que encuentra checked debería insertar un registro en la tabla subyacente, pero sólo me inserta el último, (el MessageBox me muestra todos los que, en teoría, debieran insertarse) copio el código:

```
PersonasRoles pRoles = new PersonasRoles();


        for (int i = 0; i <= (chkRoles.Items.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            if (chkRoles.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Persona " + persona.Id.ToString() + " " + Roles[i].Denominacion + " " + Roles[i].Id.ToString());
                pRoles.IdPersona = persona.Id;
                pRoles.IdRol = Roles[i].Id;
                //persona.PersonasRoles.Add(pRoles);
                Datos.PersonasRoles.Add(pRoles);
            }
        }

        Datos.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: pRoles de donde sale?

Comment: ¿Has intentado mover `Datos.SaveChanges();` a la línea siguiente de `Datos.PersonasRoles.Add(pRoles);` ? ¿Has intentado mover la primera línea de tu código mostrado: `PersonaRoles pRoles = new PersonaRoles();` dentro del if statement que tienes?

Comment: Tienes un problema: Tienes muchos roles, pero PersonasRoles tiene un solo campo para guardar esos roles. Es decir tienes un array que quieres guardarlo en IdRol siendo que este último es de tipo int. Bajo esta lógica nunca vas a poder agregar más de uno

Comment: fredyfx esta en lo cierto, se arregló simplemente moviendo el PersonaRoles pRoles = new PersonasRoles()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PersonasRoles pRoles = new PersonasRoles();

Debe estar dentro del if, así:

```c#
        for (int i = 0; i <= (chkRoles.Items.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            if (chkRoles.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                PersonasRoles pRoles = new PersonasRoles();
                MessageBox.Show("Persona " + persona.Id.ToString() + " " + Roles[i].Denominacion + " " + Roles[i].Id.ToString());
                pRoles.IdPersona = persona.Id;
                pRoles.IdRol = Roles[i].Id;
                //persona.PersonasRoles.Add(pRoles);
                Datos.PersonasRoles.Add(pRoles);
            }
        }

        Datos.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Gabriel, esa era exactamente la solución.